# asp.net database sessions are not being cleared

Tags: asp.net, oracle, locking, connection

I am Connecting with oracle database in asp.net using sqldatasource and here is my connection string

```
<add name="ConnectionString3" connectionString="Data Source=sml; User ID=sml; Password=sml; Unicode=True; Pooling=False;" providerName="System.Data.OracleClient"/>
```

I Open the Connection and after doing select something i do close the connection.Problem is that when i browse the session of Database then there two locked sessions exist there . and they don't clear till i shutdown the asp.net server.can Any one guide me what is the proper way in asp.net to connect with oracle db and then manage the connections to clear after connecting with database.I meant how i can logout from database after querying from.

**update**

```
 Dim con = New OleDbConnection("Data Source=sml; User ID=sml; Password=sml; provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle; Pooling=false")
    Try
        con.Open()
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("SELECT UPDTIME, YBAL_J, SCROLL_J, PENDING_PMT_J, YBAL_B, SCROLL_B, PENDING_PMT_B, CR_DT, OUT_BAL_J, OUT_BAL_B,SUGAR_J,CANE_CRUSH_J,RECOVERY_J,ETHANOL_J,SHEET_J,SUGAR_B,CANE_CRUSH_B,RECOVERY_B,ETHANOL_B FROM CMS20122013.V_DASH_LABELS@CMS", con)

        Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        da.Fill(ds)

        Label1.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)(0).ToString
        Label5.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)(0).ToString
        Label2.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)(1).ToString
        Label3.Text = "Scroll Issued: " & ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)(2).ToString
        Label4.Text = "Payment Pending: " & ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)(3).ToString
        Label6.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)(4).ToString
        Label7.Text = "Scroll Issued: " & ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)(5).ToString
        Label8.Text = "Payment Pending: " & ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)(6).ToString
        Label14.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)(7).ToString
        GridView4.Columns(4).HeaderText = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)(8).ToString
        GridView9.Columns(4).HeaderText = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)(9).ToString
        GridView2.Columns(0).HeaderText = "Crushing [" & ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)(11).ToString & "]"
        GridView7.Columns(0).HeaderText = "Crushing [" & ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)(16).ToString & "]"
        con.Close()
        con.Dispose()
    Catch ex As Exception
        con.Close()
        con.Dispose()
    Finally
        con.Close()
        con.Dispose()
    End Try
```

Comment: have you checked the user of whose connection is locked in oracle. try to explore that. It can give you some idea.

Comment: you should be using try, catch, finally or suggested by @Geg Smith

Comment: using try catch the one session has removed but sill one is existing with locked status.what is the issue why session become lock?

Comment: are you using transaction also?

Comment: If you are using try, catch and in finally if you are closing the connection in **finally** block then there should not be any lock session. Asp.net itself does connection pooling. Means it does not close all the connections it keep some connection open for next request. But in this case too it should not be locked.

Comment: you know that if any exception occur then it goes to catch right. But I think you don't know that it will go to finally after catch. So you don't need to write **con.Close()** and **con.Dispose()** in catch code

Comment: So What i should for the Loacked Sessions in database

Comment: Now there no problem with this code. This code can't cause locked sessions. There is some other problem. Which can be found about the information of the user session in the database.

Comment: Also I am using about 12 sqldatasources with connection string from web.config and there is no code to close that connections so what u think is there may any issue with sqldatasources?

Comment: see only dba can tell this I have know Idea about this. There is a site http://dba.stackexchange.com/ where you can get help

Comment: You have only this much code written for database or there is some other code which is interacting with database

Comment: @krshekhar yes i already told that i am also selecting data from sqldatasource abt 12 on my page

Comment: Selecting can not cause locking of session in oracle. Kindly go through you code one by one and see if there is any update or insert statement is there. Only this can cause session lock

Comment: Never I am Sure I have No any Insert Or update command in my code.Becasue My code is very long otherwise i show u here

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the c# "using" syntax?

```
using(var connection = new OracleConnection("some connection string"))
{
     connection.Open();

     //do stuff with connection
}
```

More details here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02(v=vs.100).aspx